# MariaDB 10.6.17 can i use in node-mysql2?

Tags: node.js, node-mysql2

I use mariadb 10.6.17 version and mysql2 can't connect to the server but php can login...

I tried every option

database.js

```
const { createPool } = require('mysql2');
const config = require('./config');

module.exports = createPool(config.mysql);
```

Comment: Check your config again. Ideally, this should work. `mysql.createPool({host: MYSQL_HOST,user: MYSQL_USER,password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,database: MYSQL_DATABASE,connectionLimit: 10});`